# Computed prop returning undefined

Tags: vue.js

I have a prop in a component that I want to pass with eventHub to a sibling component where I want to display the prop. However I can't make it to work and it always returns undefined.

```
   <div class="user-menu">
           {{getUsername != undefined ? 'Logged in as ' + getUsername + '!' : 'Not logged in'}}
   </div>
```

```
    computed: {
        getUsername(){
            var getUser;
        this.$eventHub.$on('current-user', username => {
             getUser = username
           })
        return getUser;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `computed` property is not the right tool for the job here. You just need a `data` property:

```js
data () {
  return {
    getUsername: null
  }
},

created () {
  this.$eventHub.$on('current-user', username => {
    this.getUsername = username
  })
}
```

Depending on how the event hub is created you would likely also need to remove the event listener when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Would the created hook work if both are sibling components? they are created at the same time and the prop is sent _after_ they are created. Is the eventHub always listening? EDIT. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: @ahzep It isn't really the event hub that's listening here, the event hub is emitting an event. It's the function we add using `$on` that's listening. That listener will continue to listen until it's removed. You can use `$once` if you only need to listen for a single occurrence. As you've noted, timing is very important here. If the listener isn't registered soon enough it could miss the event entirely. This is one reason why event buses/hubs are generally discouraged in favour of having a single piece of state as the definitive source of truth.